# Kafka retry on same topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

We would like to create a retry kafka mechanism for failures. I saw many introduced a way of have.multiple 'retry' topics. Was wondering why cant i simplify the flow by clone the message add into it a retry-counter field and just re-produce it on the same topic until reached X times and then exhausted.

What do I miss with that mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you're missing a configurable delay that should be present in retrying strategy. The simple approach you have presented will lead to very high CPU usage during some outage (for example some service you depend on is unavailable for some minutes or hours). The best approach is to have exponential backoff strategy - with each retry you increase a delay after which a message processing is retried again. And this "delivery delay" is something Kafka doesn't support.

Comment: so now i need to implement backoff strategy. what about DLQ? then it will require me to start maintaining state per message?

Comment: The whole state for a message is just number of retries alredy done (except for the message content of course). A message queue will keep "delivery delay" for you which you set when sending a message to DLQ.

Comment: what do you mean by "A message queue" ? could you please explain. also where am I going to store the number of retry attempts per message ?

Comment: Just search for the term in the internet. Number of retries can be attached to the message as a custom header (message headers are quite common feature of most messaging systems).

Comment: so you suggest that ill create some kind of common lib that will maintain the number of re-tries inside a message header and will re-produce the same message to the same kafka back again once it fails? adding to that a decision logic that if retry number has reached re-dispatch to dedicated DLQ.. quite lots of logic to write ourselfs right?

Comment: True. And use a message queue for messages to retry, not Kafka. Kafka is not a message queue. It's a streaming platform. I'm afraid you cannot have this functionality solved based only on Kafka.

Comment: any message queue solution with high performances you would recommand?

Comment: Try some open source solutions first. ActiveMQ Artemis (not to be confused with Apache ActiveMQ) looks very promising. Other ones worth to try are RabbitMQ and ActiveMQ.

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure if I understand the question correctly. Nevertheless, I would suggest that you have some Kafka 'retry' strategies.

- Messages in 'retry' topics are already sorted in ‘retry_timestamp’
  order
- Because postponing message processing in case of failure is not a trivial process
- If you would like to postpone processing of
  some messages, you can republish them to separate topics, one for
  each with some delay value
- The  failed messages processing can be
  achieved by cloning the message and later republishing it to one of
  the retry topics
- Consumers of retry topics could block the thread
  (unless it is time to process the message)

Comment: thanks for your reply. how Messages in 'retry' topics are already sorted in ‘retry_timestamp’ order ?? i mean if i take them in batch there is a chanse that ill miss the retry buffer time coz the same message wont be on that  batch